# Change HTML Tags from fetched data with JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I am trying to change HTML tags from Data I'm fetching with an API. I am at a point that the text from the API is being displayed on the page but this text includes header tags that I would like to make a different header. For example  to an . I have tried to use: 
    function(){
        $('p').replaceWith('divs rule!');
    });
but this applies to the whole page. Is this possible?

Comment: If you don't want it to apply to the whole page, then write your replace just on the returned data as the Explosion Pills below suggests, or change your selector to something more restrictive. Perhaps using the parent container the data is being inserted into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the data at retrieval time:

```
.done(function (html) {
    $(html).find("p").replaceWith("divs rule!");
});
```

Comment: +1 This makes some assumptions on how he is getting his data, but is a very straight forward solution if your assumption is correct.

Comment: Can I determine what multiple tags I want to replace with one tag?

Comment: @JTNolan yes?  what do you mean?

Comment: I'm new to Javascript... specifically I want to change All header tags to a selection and change them specifically to an h4.

Comment: @JTNolan what is a selection?

Comment: $Message = $array[$i]['Message'];
        $allow = '<p><h1><h2><h3><h4>';
        $clear = strip_tags($Message, $allow);

Comment: message is what is being gathered from the API

Comment: @JTNolan `.replaceWith("<div>")`?

Comment: @JTNolan you want to replace a *specific* div or you want to replace all `<p>` tags with a specific div?

Comment: and how do you add code to chat or a post on this site? like in the little greyed out section

Comment: I want to change all <h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, and <h5> tags to <h4> tags within a specific <p> tag. the p tag seen at the end of this code...    $Message = $array[$i]['Message'];
    $allow = '<p><h1><h2><h3><h4>';
    $clear = strip_tags($Message, $allow);
    echo "<p class=''>" . $clear . "</p>";

Comment: @JTNolan it would probably be a lot easier to do that on the PHP side using `DOMDocument` / cloneNode/replaceChild